# How can I add a flag in PostgreSQL source code that works in both frontend and backend?

Tags: postgresql, c

I'm trying to do some changes to postgresql source code. I want to add a flag  that works in both frontend and backend. Here is what I have done so far.

1- I created my header file mine.h in which I declared my global flag as follows.

```
extern int CMD_FLAG;
extern void init_vars();// this function to initialize CMD_FLAG
```

2- I included mine.h in pgsql/src/include/c.h since it can be seen by both frontend and backend.

3- in pgsql/src/port/exec.c I wrote the body of init_vars() function that initializes CMD_FLAG as follows:

```
int CMD_FLAG;

void init_vars(){
   CMD_FLAG =-1;
}
```

4- In pgsql/src/backend/main/main.c , I called

```
init_vars();
```

when I compiled Postgresql, I didn't get any error. However, when I tried to print the flag value, it had different values in backend and fronted.

For example, when I printed it in function "HandleSlashCmds", which is in frontend, the value was 0 whereas it was supposed to be -1.

If I make any change to the flag in frontend, the change applies only to frontend  functions. On the other hand, If I make any change to the flag in back, the change applies only to backend  functions.

I think somehow there are 2 copies of the flag one for each end. How can I make both ends access the same value?

Comment: I'd call it a pretty brave undertaking to modify `postgresql` given that you have this question. Frontend and backend run in different processes. C `globals` have (roughly) the scope of a single process. You'll have to deploy operating system level mechanisms for some kind of shared memory but it would be a cleaner approach if you make the client tell the server about its configuration or vice versa, depending on what you want to do. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The frontend and backend are different processes, communicating over a network protocol.

The closest thing to what you want is a GUC ("grand unified configuration") variable. You can define a custom GUC in the backend server with `DefineCustomIntVariable` and set the `GUC_REPORT` flag on it so that when it gets changed by a `SET` statement, etc, the new value gets reported to the client using an asynchronous notification on the wire protocol. The client application can detect this change and apply the new setting.

Similarly, when the variable is changed on the client it can send a `SET` query to assign a new value on the server.

There are obviously delays imposed by this, especially since the protocol only allows `SET` queries and notification responses at certain times. In practice you'll only see changes in variables after queries complete. So it's *not* the same thing as just setting a variable in memory.

Additionally, a GUC can have a *separate value* in each backend session in PostgreSQL, since it's a multiprocess shared-nothing-by-default architecture. So if you want to set a variable across all sessions a GUC isn't suitable, and you need to allocate a variable in shared memory using your extension ... but in that case you can't automatically report the value to the client.

Whatever you are trying to do, I strongly suspect this is not the way to do it.

---

By the way, you really shouldn't have to patch PostgreSQL for this. An extension's `_PG_init()` can run at server startup time if it's listed in `shared_preload_libraries`. It can allocate shared memory segments, define GUCs, etc at that time.

---

If you *really* have to ensure that there's a variable that's the same between frontend and backend, and if the frontend and backend run on the same host as the same user, you might be able to do something using mmap'd anonymous memory and atomics. It'd be difficult to get this right and at your current level it'll involve a *lot* of study.

Comment: Thanks. Let me explain what I want to do. You might help me to do it in the sever side. I want to record all tables'  ids of the queries that saved to a file using the "\o" command. 
My idea was to set a flag when "HandleSlashCmds" function is called in the frontend and the in backend I have a function to collect table ids of all queries. However, it seems that I have to do a lot of work to do to change flag's value. 
Is there any part in the backend that can help me to know if the query result was saved to a file using "\o"? 
Thanks again.

Comment: @Dareen  No there isn't. What about `\copy`? Or stdio redirection? or other clients like psycopg2 writing to files? Is this meant to be some kind of audit log?